# ILI9341 Library for arduino

Tags: arduino, programming, display, prototyping, ili9341

I'm writing an arduino library for ILI9341 tft display.
I tried to write on the display but nothing appears. Why? 
How can I solve the problem ?

My source code:

```
    /* DISPLAY PINS */
#define LCD_RST A4    //reset
#define LCD_CS A3
#define LCD_RS A2
#define LCD_WR A1
#define LCD_RD A0



#define LCD_D0 8
#define LCD_D1 9
#define LCD_D2 2
#define LCD_D3 3
#define LCD_D4 4
#define LCD_D5 5
#define LCD_D6 6
#define LCD_D7 7





void setup()
{

    delay(1000);
    //init serial
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //init digital pins
    initLcdPins();
    delay(100);

    setPower1();
    memoryAccessControl();
    setPixelFormat(18);


    displayOn();

    delay(100);
    setCol();
    setPage();
    writeMemory();
}

// Add the main program code into the continuous loop() function
void loop()
{


}




void initLcdPins() {
    pinMode(LCD_RST, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_CS, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_RS, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_WR, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_RD, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D0, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D7, OUTPUT);


    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);



    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, 0);


}



void  setAddress(byte d7, byte d6, byte d5, byte d4, byte d3, byte d2, byte d1, byte d0) {



    //SEND COMMAND TO THE ILI9341
    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);

        delay(10);


    //SET BYTE
    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, d0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, d1);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, d2);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, d3);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, d4);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, d5);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, d6);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, d7);



    delay(10);

    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);

    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, 0);



    delay(20);

}

void setParameter(byte d7, byte d6, byte d5, byte d4, byte d3, byte d2, byte d1, byte d0) {





    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);



    delay(10);


    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, d0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, d1);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, d2);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, d3);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, d4);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, d5);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, d6);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, d7);


    delay(10);

    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);

    delay(10);




    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, 0);

    delay(20);
}


void setPower1() {
    setAddress(1 ,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    setParameter(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1);
}

void setCol() {
    setAddress(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0);


    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );  //SC
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);  //EC



}

void setPage() {

    setAddress(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1);


    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);  //SC
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);  //EC

}



void writeMemory() {
    setAddress(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0);


    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);


    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);


    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    setParameter(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);




}


void setPixelFormat(int format) {


    setAddress(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0);


    if (format == 16) {
        setParameter(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);
    }
    else if (format == 18) {
        setParameter(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);
    }


}







void displayOn() {
    setAddress(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1);


}


void memoryAccessControl() {
    setAddress(0, 0, 1,1, 0, 1, 1, 1);

    setParameter(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

The datasheet of the ILI9341: [Link](https://www.displaytech-us.com/sites/default/files/driver-ic-data-sheet/Ilitek-ILI9341.pdf)

Edit :

I have updated the source code but the display does not show anything yet.
Do you have any suggestions?

The updated source code:

```
/* DISPLAY PINS */
#define LCD_RST A4    //reset
#define LCD_CS A3
#define LCD_RS A2
#define LCD_WR A1
#define LCD_RD A0



#define LCD_D0 8
#define LCD_D1 9
#define LCD_D2 2
#define LCD_D3 3
#define LCD_D4 4
#define LCD_D5 5
#define LCD_D6 6
#define LCD_D7 7





/* DISPLAY REGISTERS*/

#define SLEEP_OUT 0x11
#define COLUMN_ADDRESS_SET 0x2A
#define PAGE_ADDRESS_SET 0x2B
#define MEMORY_WRITE 0x2C
#define MEMORY_ACCESS_CONTROL 0x36
#define PIXEL_FORMAT_SET 0x3A
#define POWER_CONTROL_1 0xC0
#define DISPLAY_ON 0x29










void setup()
{

//  delay(1000);
    //init serial
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //init digital pins
    initLcdPins();
    delay(100);

    setPower1();
    delay(100);
    memoryAccessControl();
    delay(100);
    setPixelFormat(18);
    delay(100);


    displayOn();
    delay(100);




    delay(100);
    setCol();
    delay(100);
    setPage();
    delay(100);
    writeMemory();


    sleepOut();
}

// Add the main program code into the continuous loop() function
void loop()
{


}




void initLcdPins() {
    pinMode(LCD_RST, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_CS, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_RS, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_WR, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_RD, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D0, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D7, OUTPUT);


    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);



    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, 0);


}



void setAddress(byte data) {
    //SEND COMMAND TO THE ILI9341
    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);

    delay(10);


    //SET BYTE
    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, (data >> 0) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, (data >> 1) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, (data >> 2) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, (data >> 3) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, (data >> 4) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, (data >> 5) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, (data >> 6) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, (data >> 7) & 0x01);


    delay(10);

    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);

    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, 0);

    delay(20);

}



void setParameter(byte data) {





    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);



    delay(10);

    //SET BYTE
    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, (data >> 0) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, (data >> 1) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, (data >> 2) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, (data >> 3) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, (data >> 4) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, (data >> 5) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, (data >> 6) & 0x01);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, (data >> 7) & 0x01);


    delay(10);

    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);

    delay(10);




    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, 0);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, 0);

    delay(20);
}






void setPower1() {
    setAddress(POWER_CONTROL_1);

    setParameter(0x2B);
}






void setCol() {


    setAddress(COLUMN_ADDRESS_SET);


    setParameter(0x0 );  //SC
    setParameter(0x5);  //EC



}





void setPage() {

    setAddress(PAGE_ADDRESS_SET);


    setParameter(0x0);  //SC
    setParameter(0x5);  //EC

}



void writeMemory() {
    setAddress(MEMORY_WRITE);




    for (int i = 0; i < (18*25); i++) {
        setParameter(i);
    }
}


void setPixelFormat(int format) {


    setAddress(PIXEL_FORMAT_SET);




    if (format == 16) {
        setParameter(0x55);
    }
    else if (format == 18) {
        setParameter(0x66);
    }


}







void displayOn() {
    setAddress(DISPLAY_ON);


}


void memoryAccessControl() {
    setAddress(MEMORY_ACCESS_CONTROL);

    setParameter(0x48);
}





void sleepOut() {
    setAddress(SLEEP_OUT);
}
```

EDIT:

```
/* DISPLAY REGISTERS*/

#define SLEEP_OUT 0x11
#define COLUMN_ADDRESS_SET 0x2A
#define PAGE_ADDRESS_SET 0x2B
#define MEMORY_WRITE 0x2C
#define MEMORY_ACCESS_CONTROL 0x36
#define PIXEL_FORMAT_SET 0x3A
#define POWER_CONTROL_1 0xC0
#define DISPLAY_ON 0x29
#define GAMMA_SET 0x26
#define DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS 0x51







// adapted from LCD_ID_Reader from http://misc.ws/lcd_information
// controllers either read as 16-bit or as a sequence of 8-bit values

//-- Arduino UNO or Mega 2560 Plugged as shield
#define LCD_RST A4
#define LCD_CS A3
#define LCD_RS A2
#define LCD_WR A1
#define LCD_RD A0

#define LCD_D0 8
#define LCD_D1 9
#define LCD_D2 2
#define LCD_D3 3
#define LCD_D4 4
#define LCD_D5 5
#define LCD_D6 6
#define LCD_D7 7

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    lcdInit();
    lcdReset();      //ensures that controller is in default state
                     //    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) readReg(i, 7, "f.k"); 




    delay(500);

    setPixelFormat(18);



    setCol(0, 0xA);
    setPage(0, 0xA);

    writeMemory(0xA, 0xA);





}

void loop()
{
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

void printhex(uint8_t val)
{
    if (val < 0x10) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(val, HEX);
}

void readReg(uint16_t reg, uint8_t n, const char *msg)
{
    uint8_t val8;
    lcdReset();
    lcdSetWriteDir();
    lcdWriteCommand(0xB0);     //Command Access Protect
    lcdWriteData(0x00);        //looks wrong
                               /*
                               lcdWriteCommand(0xF6);
                               lcdWriteData(0x01);
                               lcdWriteData(0x01);
                               lcdWriteData(0x03);
                               */
    lcdWriteCommand(reg);
    Serial.print("reg(0x");
    printhex(reg >> 8);
    printhex(reg);
    Serial.print(")");
    lcdSetReadDir();
    while (n--) {
        val8 = lcdReadData8();
        Serial.print(" ");
        printhex(val8);
    }
    lcdSetWriteDir();
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(msg);
}

void lcdInit()
{
    pinMode(LCD_CS, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
    pinMode(LCD_RS, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);
    pinMode(LCD_WR, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);
    pinMode(LCD_RD, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);
    pinMode(LCD_RST, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
}

void lcdReset()
{
    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, LOW);
    delay(2);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
    delay(10);             //allow controller to re-start
}

void lcdWrite8(uint16_t data)
{
    digitalWrite(LCD_D0, data & 1);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D1, (data & 2) >> 1);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D2, (data & 4) >> 2);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D3, (data & 8) >> 3);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D4, (data & 16) >> 4);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D5, (data & 32) >> 5);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D6, (data & 64) >> 6);
    digitalWrite(LCD_D7, (data & 128) >> 7);
}

uint16_t lcdRead8()
{
    uint16_t result = digitalRead(LCD_D7);
    result <<= 1;
    result |= digitalRead(LCD_D6);
    result <<= 1;
    result |= digitalRead(LCD_D5);
    result <<= 1;
    result |= digitalRead(LCD_D4);
    result <<= 1;
    result |= digitalRead(LCD_D3);
    result <<= 1;
    result |= digitalRead(LCD_D2);
    result <<= 1;
    result |= digitalRead(LCD_D1);
    result <<= 1;
    result |= digitalRead(LCD_D0);

    return result;
}

void lcdSetWriteDir()
{
    pinMode(LCD_D0, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D7, OUTPUT);
}


void lcdSetReadDir()
{
    pinMode(LCD_D0, INPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D1, INPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D2, INPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D3, INPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D4, INPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D5, INPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D6, INPUT);
    pinMode(LCD_D7, INPUT);
}

void lcdWriteData(uint16_t data)
{
    lcdSetWriteDir();
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);

    lcdWrite8(data >> 8);

    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);

    lcdWrite8(data);

    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}

void lcdWriteCommand(uint16_t command)
{
    lcdSetWriteDir();
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);
    lcdWrite8(command >> 8);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);
    lcdWrite8(command);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}

uint8_t lcdReadData8()
{
    uint8_t result;
    lcdSetReadDir();
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    result = lcdRead8();
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);

    delayMicroseconds(10);

    return result;
}


uint16_t lcdReadData16()
{
    uint16_t result;
    result = lcdReadData8() << 8;
    result |= lcdReadData8();
    return result;
}


void lcdWriteRegister(uint16_t addr, uint16_t data)
{
    lcdWriteCommand(addr);
    lcdWriteData(data);
}







void setCol(uint16_t from, uint16_t at) {


    lcdWriteCommand(COLUMN_ADDRESS_SET);


    lcdWriteData(from);  //SC
    lcdWriteData(at);  //EC



}
void setPage(uint16_t from, uint16_t at){

    lcdWriteCommand(PAGE_ADDRESS_SET);

    lcdWriteData(from);  //SP
    lcdWriteData(at);  //EP

}
void writeMemory(uint16_t data, uint16_t b) {





    lcdWriteCommand(MEMORY_WRITE);

    //setParameter(data);





    for (int i = 0; i < data; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            //16 BIT COLORS
            lcdWriteData(0xFFFF);

        }
    }

}

void setPixelFormat(int format) {


    lcdWriteCommand(PIXEL_FORMAT_SET);




    if (format == 16) {
        lcdWriteData(0x55);
    }
    else if (format == 18) {
        lcdWriteData(0x66);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the address you give in `memoryAccessControl()` is 0x37 (Vertical Scrolling Start Address) not 0x36.

You also need to use the sleep out command 0x11 in your setup() function.

Edit: Chip select changes

```
void setPower1() {
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    setAddress(POWER_CONTROL_1);
    setParameter(0x2B);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}

void setCol() {
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    setAddress(COLUMN_ADDRESS_SET);
    setParameter( 0x0 );  //SC
    setParameter( 0x5 );  //EC
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}

void setPage() {
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    setAddress(PAGE_ADDRESS_SET);
    setParameter(0x0);  //SC
    setParameter(0x5);  //EC
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}


void writeMemory() {
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    setAddress(MEMORY_WRITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < (18*25); i++) {
        setParameter(i);
    }
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}


void setPixelFormat(int format) {
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    setAddress(PIXEL_FORMAT_SET);
    if (format == 16) {
        setParameter(0x55);
    }
    else if (format == 18) {
        setParameter(0x66);
    }

    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}

void displayOn() {
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    setAddress(DISPLAY_ON);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}


void memoryAccessControl() {
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    setAddress(MEMORY_ACCESS_CONTROL);
    setParameter(0x48);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}

void sleepOut() {
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, LOW);
    setAddress(SLEEP_OUT);
    digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);
}
void setAddress(byte data) {
    //SEND COMMAND TO THE ILI9341
    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
    //digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);  <--------
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);
    /*rest of the function*/
}
void setParameter(byte data) {
    digitalWrite(LCD_RST, HIGH);
    //digitalWrite(LCD_CS, HIGH);  <--------
    digitalWrite(LCD_RS, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LCD_WR, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LCD_RD, HIGH);
    /*rest of the function*/
}
```

Comment: I have edited  the source code  but the display shows nothing.

Comment: One other thing i overlooked was that you're not toggling chip select, it's always high. Try pulling CS low before `setAddress()` and setting it high again after the last `setParameter()` in each of your command functions.

Comment: Also don't forget to remove it from being set high again in the beginning of each call to `setAddress()` and `setParameter()`

Comment: I have  updated my code but the display is black.

Comment: I just tested out similar code on the microcontroller I have, it worked for me. Can you edit your original post's code with the changes you made? I would also double check your pin connections at this point. Just to double check, is the back light on?

Comment: Yes, the back ligth is on

Comment: Using the code you most recently added it also does not work for me either. The initialization function is missing display on and sleep out commands. Can you check the IM[0:2] pins and make sure they're set for an 8 bit parallel interface (all 0)?

Comment: I'm using a board that I bought on ebay so I do not know where are the pins IM [0: 2] .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84597/discussion-between-adam-vz-and-jhon-tonini).